# How many endings does Cultist Simulator have?

Tags: cultist-simulator

I recently started playing Cultist Simulator and I got the "Evening falls" ending. How many endings does the game have in total?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now there are around five possible endings, I believe. There are also four legacies. There are plans to add in additional endings and legacies in future DLC (which you will get for free if you bought the Perpetual Edition, which if you bought the game today you certainly have). And there are different ways of getting the three main endings, depending on your cult choices, expedition results, and mistakes.